# length indicator with binary mode in C++

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

Using C++, I'm writing to my file in binary mode, using length indicator method like this:

```
    ostringstream ID;
    ID << b.getID(); //where b.getID() returns unsigned long
    string IDStr = ID.str();


    size_t IDlength = IDStr.length();
    stream.write ((char *)(&IDlength), sizeof(size_t));
    stream.write ((char *)(&IDStr),IDlength);
```

I'm reading it like this :

```
    string IDStr,ID;        
    stream.read ((char *) (&IDStr), sizeof(size_t));

    int Result;
    stringstream convert(IDStr); 
    if ( !(convert >> Result) )//give the value to Result using the chars in string
    Result = 0;//if that fails set Result to 0

    stream.read ((char *)ID,Result);
```

is this right? and how can i suitably read from it, i can't seem to get the reading code right, any help please?

Comment: Use `IDStr.c_str()` to get the content of the string, not `&IDStr`.

Comment: If you want help with the reading code you'll need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: The first thing you wrote was a `size_t`, so that's the first thing you need to read. A `string` is not a `size_t`, nor is it a `char *`.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the string...

```
size_t IDlength = IDStr.length();
stream.write ((char const*)(&IDlength), sizeof(size_t));
stream.write (IDStr.c_str() ,IDlength);
```

Reading the string...

```
size_t IDlength;
stream.read ((char *)(&IDlength), sizeof(size_t));

// Allocate memory to read the string.
char* s = new char[IDlength+1];

// Read the string.
stream.read (s, IDlength);

// Make sure to null-terminate the C string.
s[IDlength] = '\0';

// Create the std::string using the C string.
// Make sure the terminating null character is
// not left out.
IDStr.assign(s, IDlength+1);

// Deallocate memory allocated to read the C string.
delete [] s;
```

Comment: Unnecessary cast. not exception safe, doesn't handle embedded nulls, syntax error.

Comment: @AlanStokes, Fixed the syntax error. Thanks for letting me know. The casts are necessary. `istream::read` and `ostream::write` expect `char*` as the argument type. Without the casts, you should get compiler errors. I don't know why you think it doesn't handle embedded nulls. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: `IDStr.c_str()` returns the correct type, so you don't need the cast there (and it would be better to cast to `char const *` for `write`). `IDStr = s` will stop at the first zero byte it sees; you know how many bytes you have, so you can call `assign`.

Comment: If you'd now discard the useless null byte from the read buffer and replace it with a vector you would be even closer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Perhaps I am missing something obvious but that did not make sense to me at all. Are you suggesting that the terminating null character is useless if the string can contain embedded null characters?

Comment: You only need a null byte in order to use code that assumes a null-terminated sequence. Such code is in `std::string` e.g. the ctor and assignment operator taking a char pointer, but not `assign()`. Internally, it will automatically add an extra null character itself, which is in order to interface with similar code, e.g. via c_str(). You don't need to provide space in your input buffer though.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The documentation for the version of `std::string::assign` I am using doesn't say anything about automatically appending a null character. I personally think it is safer to add that instead of relying on undocumented behavior.

Comment: `c_str()` returns a null-terminated string. For a `string s`, `s[0]` is guaranteed to be a null character, unlike a vector where that would be an out-of-bounds access. For convenience, implementations store this extra character in their internal storage, but they don't have to, as their operation doesn't normally depend on the string being null-terminated. Also, I bet that your `assign()` docs don't mention any requirements concerning that the string is null-terminated. That would also kill the possibility of assigning a substring...